# Windows Phone 8.1 - Draw text over photo, but without showing the photo

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I'm porting an Android application I've made to Windows Phone 8.1. I want my app to do the following: pick up a photo from the gallery, put some text on it, and then save the image back to the gallery. On Android I have been able to accomplish it, but on Windows Phone 8.1 the only solution I have found is to use RenderTargetBitmap, but this solution requires to display the image on screen, but I don't want to display it.

Any ideas?

Thank you a lot

Comment: Your image doesn't necessarily need to be on the screen - you can render it behind other items (or even off the screen, but within the visual tree). I have done something similar to create custom live tiles. However, I haven't tried this method on WP8.1 yet. I did a blog post a while back for Windows 8.1 live tiles, but the technique should work for phone too (apologies for the VB.net) : http://grogansoft.com/blog/?p=40

Comment: Thank you! Rendering the image off the screen solved my problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the question can be marked as answered:

Your image doesn't necessarily need to be on the screen - you can render it behind other items (or even off the screen, but within the visual tree). I have done something similar to create custom live tiles. However, I haven't tried this method on WP8.1 yet. I did a blog post a while back for Windows 8.1 live tiles, but the technique should work for phone too (apologies for the VB.net) : grogansoft.com/blog/?p=40

Comment: Thank you another time! But I still have a problem: how can I render an element such as a TextBlock outside the screen, without affecting the bitmap generated by RenderTargetBitmap?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. What is the purpose of text off the screen if you are not rendering it? The user can't see it? What is the scenario?

Comment: I want to add the text inside a TextBlock (predefined) to a bitmap, using RenderTargetBitmap. I don't want the user to see that text. The bitmap is then saved to the gallery

Comment: You've completely confused me. Isn't the whole point of doing this off screen so the user doesn't see it? If it's off the screen the user can't see it. You can render your control (With image, text, etc.) to a bitmap without the user seeing any of it. Do you need another result other than saving an image with text 'superimposed' on it?

Comment: No, that's exactly what I want: "saving an image with text 'superimposed' on it". But the problem is that I tried to set the TextBlock outside of the screen by setting some Margins, and the result is that the generated Bitmap is MUCH larger than the original TextBlock. This doesn't happen if I put the TextBlock, let's say, on the middle of the screen

Comment: There are a couple of guesses that spring to mind - make sure the items exist at the start of the page (i.e. don't instantiate them from code behind), and make sure you give the UI time to draw before trying to export the bitmap. Also, something I do in WP7 apps which might help is to do all this within the screen area instead, but place content in front of the image/text so the user doesn't see it (e.g. an opaque background).